# Javascript refactor map example to use reduce

Tags: javascript

As an exercise I'm trying to convert a map example to use reduce:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];

numbers.map(function(a,b) {
    return a+b;
});
// [1, 3, 5, 7]
```

my attempt for same example with reduce:

```
numbers.reduce(
  (sum, elem) => {
    sum.push(elem + elem); // how can one add the index of array to the number instead of doubling it?
    return sum;
  }, []);
// [2, 4, 6, 8], instead I want: [1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your result with reduce**. Pass the third parameter, which is the index

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];


var arr = numbers.reduce(
  (sum, elem, index) => {
    sum.push(elem + index);
    return sum;
  }, []);

console.log(arr);
```

**But**

Your `map` function works as you want only by accidently :).

`map` function accepts as parameters not the 2 sibling items, but an item and it's index.

See here. If you change the pre-last item, you will get an other behaviour. In your logic the last item must be `11`,if it accepts 2 sibling items, but not it is still `7`, because it accepts the item and it's index.

**Example with changed data.**

```
1 -> 1 + 0 (index) = 1
2 -> 2 + 1 (index) = 3
3 -> 3 + 2 (index) = 5
4 -> 4 + 3 (index) = 7
```

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 7, 4];

var arr = numbers.map(function(a,b) {
    return a+b;
});

console.log(arr);
```

**Output**

```
1 -> 1 + 0 (index) = 1
2 -> 2 + 1 (index) = 3
7 -> 7 + 2 (index) = 9
4 -> 4 + 3 (index) = 7
```

`reduce` function accepts in it's basic form two parameters, the item of the array and the returned value from the previous iteration.

So I think you understood these functions not well.

You can read more in the [**Array#map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and **[Array#reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)**

Comment: hmm, I just wanted the same result of the map example with reduce. In your answer you elaborate the map example but didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the previous item with a check for truthyness and the actual item. Return the array with concatinated value.

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    result = numbers.reduce((r, a, i, aa) => r.concat((aa[i - 1] || 0) + a), []);

console.log(result);
```